# How to make keys from columns using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, key

I'm trying to make the columns into key pair for the column next to it.
This is my dataframe:

```
file = ('big.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(file)

df.head()

World   Europe   Scandinavia   
xxxx    vvvvv    TTTTT
rrrr    sssss    aaaaa
```

Is there a way in pandas to make the columns keys for each others, like in a dict?
I want World to bey key to Europe, and Europe to be key to Scandinavia

|World|Europe|Scandinavia|

*EDIT*

Forgot to mention that I'm trying to convert the dataframe into a json-dict, so that I have the columns as nested objects.

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output. Creating questions with a minimal reproducible example will help people to answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to set the index.

```
df = df.set_index('World')
```

Then you can use:

```
df.loc['xxxx']['World']
```

You can either create two dataframes with two different index:

```
df1 = df[['World', 'Europe']].set_index('World')
df2 = df[['Europe', 'Scandinavia']].set_index('Europe')
```

You can also convert those directly to dicts:

```
d1 = df1.to_dict()
d2 = df2.to_dict()
```

Comment: Closer to what I want, but after the "d1 = df1.to_dict()"-command it will drop all rows and just keep 1 row for World, and 1 row for Europe